# Rails: Sending email after filling contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, mail-form

I'd like to create contact form using [this](http://l4u.github.io/articles/create-a-rails-4-site-with-contact-us-form/) tutorial

At the end of that is writen that I should configure SMTP, so in config/environments/developement.rb I set

```
 config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'myproject.c9.io'}
```

(I'm using rails on c9.io)

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "gmail.com",
  :user_name            => "myusername",
  :password             => "mypassword",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I'm fairly new in rails and especially in sending emails, so I'd like to ask, because I don't get message on my email address when I fill form and send, what should I do to get a confirmation of correct sending. I know that there is a lot of tutorials on the Internet but now I'm in the muddle, so I'll be grateful for explanation.

Comment: Add,  
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
before config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'myproject.c9.io'}
Please let me know, if it did not work for you :-) Don't forget to restart the server.

Comment: It works, thank you. But I have a question, now I get message which I sent but extra there is message from <mailer-daemon@googlemail.com> : Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently. Maybe you know what is the reason?

Comment: Glad to here that. Yeah, you have sent an email to someone email address. make sure that email address actually exist.
You forget to vote up my comment :-)

Comment: Ohh, I understand now what's going on :) thank you! I'd like to upvote your comment but I haven't arrow by it

Answer (score 3):

Add these config to your development.rb [reference](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail)

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'myproject.c9.io'}

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'gmail.com',
  user_name:            'myusername',
  password:             'mypassword',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  
}
```

Comment: if it goes to spam folder make sure to edit your devise.rb to be: initializer   config.mailer_sender = 'youremail@gmail.com'